# Wordpress anonymous user can not access profile page

Tags: wordpress, contacts, profile

So I am trying to setup a profile that the anonymous (not logged in) user can access on CiviCRM with WordPress.

I have read the other threads and tried setting the the WordPress Access Control options as suggested but it still did not work... it keeps re-directing to the home page of the wordpress install.

So then what I tried was ticking ALL boxes for the Anonymous user in the WordPress Access Control (yes every single one) which would theoretically be the same permissions that a CiviCRM administrator would have.

But even with every permission granted, it still does not show the profile and still continues to redirect back to the wordpress homepage.

I then even tried de-activating all wordpress plugins (except civicrm) and had the same behavior.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: I am using this to send a link to my anonymous user:

```
https://mydomain.com/civicrm/profile/edit?gid=14&reset=1&cid={contact.id}&{contact.checksum}
```

Which sends me a link something like this:

```
https://mydomain.com/civicrm/profile/edit?gid=14&reset=1&cid=1106&cs=b44ac099f6e0c7624006cc12d5e04509_1655496640_888
```

Comment: Dohh ... it is supposed to be *&id=* not *&cid=* (facepalm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the issue turned out to that I mistakenly used `&cid=` instead of `&id=`

So correct link to send in an email to the user with tokens is:

```
https://mydomain.com/civicrm/profile/edit?gid=14&reset=1&id={contact.id}&{contact.checksum}
```

I will post back with more details shortly about persmissions as well.